# Reading a Fast5-file with Python

Tags: python, nanopore, jupyter, base-calling, fast5

I am trying to extract data from fast5-file with python 3.9.13 in Ubuntu. I have found a library "fast5_research"(This package comprises an API to HDF containers used by the research groups within Oxford Nanopore Technologies), installed on my PC and updated my software with "sudo apt update". According to [tutorial](https://nanoporetech.github.io/fast5_research/examples.html) I attempted to read fasta5-file with the next code:

```
from fast5_research import Fast5
filename='/home/master/Desktop/0.fast5'
with Fast5(filename) as fh:
    raw = fh.get_read(raw=True)
    summary = fh.summary()
print('Raw is {} samples long.'.format(len(raw)))
print('Summary {}.'.format(summary))
```

but as a result, I have an error:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_410530/3650860803.py in <module>
      4 from fast5_research import Fast5
      5 filename='/home/master/Desktop/0.fast5'
----> 6 with Fast5(filename) as fh:
      7     raw = fh.get_read(raw=True)
      8     summary = fh.summary()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/fast5_research/fast5.py in __init__(self, fname, read)
     85 
     86         # Attach channel_meta as attributes, slightly redundant
---> 87         for k, v in _clean_attrs(self[self.__channel_meta_path__].attrs).items():
     88             setattr(self, k, v)
     89         # Backward compat.

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.9/site-packages/h5py/_hl/group.py in __getitem__(self, name)
    175                 raise ValueError("Invalid HDF5 object reference")
    176         else:
--> 177             oid = h5o.open(self.id, self._e(name), lapl=self._lapl)
    178 
    179         otype = h5i.get_type(oid)

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/_objects.pyx in h5py._objects.with_phil.wrapper()

h5py/h5o.pyx in h5py.h5o.open()

KeyError: 'Unable to open object (component not found)'
```

How to fix this error?

Comment: similar too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28782487/read-hdf5-based-file-as-a-numpy-array-in-python

Comment: HDF5View should do the same as the post, just more "point and click"

Answer (score 0):

The code looks fine `fast5` is simply `HDF5` format (rapid I/O).

The error,

> 'Unable to open object (component not found)'

You are not the only person [to have this error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55473368/h5py-randomly-unable-to-open-object-component-not-found) and it could be a bug in the code with `hdf5` in Python. Just to note I use `hdf5` without a any problem.

1. Problem with the installation (?), this is the best guess to resolve it but I notice from your error log .. the errors are coming from Anaconda, I assume you made a `conda` installation, but the post implies `apt-get`?? Just check where the package is located.

```
conda install -c hcc fast5-research
```

Then perform a conda environment creation  and activation of the same package as [here](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/20161/how-to-run-how-are-we-stranded-here). I think you've already done that. `anaconda3` is definitely your Python3 version ... and in that case it might be better to do the full `conda` installation because it stops things getting mixed up.

**NOTE**
There is a Docker container

```
docker pull quay.io/biocontainers/fast5-research
```

I would recommend using this (it will almost certainly work), if you know how to leverage Docker (which is sort of complicated).

2. File corruption ... examine the file via the HDFView GUI, here https://www.hdfgroup.org/downloads/hdfview/ . If you can't see within the file via the viewer - I think the file has a problem. Perhaps examine via hdf5 ... wait no that gets complicated.
3. It can't find the file or a path error (below).

Then kindly try:

```
from fast5_research import Fast5
import pathlib as Path
import sys

filename=Path('/home/master/Desktop/0.fast5')
if filename.exists():
    print ('Okay {} is fine.'.format(filename))
    filename='/home/master/Desktop/0.fast5'
else:
    pathway = Path(__file__).absolute().parent
    if not Path(pathway, '0.fast5').is_file():
        raise ValueError ('Sorry filename has not been found')
        sys.exit()
    filename = str(Path(pathway, '0.fast5'))
try:
    if Path(filename).exists():
        with Fast5(filename) as fh:
            raw = fh.get_read(raw=True)
            summary = fh.summary()
        print('Raw is {} samples long.'.format(len(raw)))
        print('Summary {}.'.format(summary))
except Exception as err:
    print ("The error codes are {} and {}".format(err.message, err.args))
```

Please execute the code in the same `dir` as `'/home/master/Desktop/'` or maybe just `'/home/Desktop`

In `Fasta5` will almost certainly take a `path` from `pathlib` but I've erred in case not. `HDF5` will certainly accept a `pathlib` pathway.

I've not tested it but just post back what happens.