# How to run how_are_we_stranded_here?

Tags: rna-seq

I'm trying to run the python library called how_are_we_stranded_here. I have installed with `pip install how_are_we_stranded_here`. I have also installed its dependencies i.e kallisto 0.44.0 and RSeQC. On how_are_we_stranded_here's pypi page, it gives the following command under the usage heading:

```
 check_strandedness --gtf Yeast.gtf --transcripts Yeast_cdna.fasta \
--reads_1 Sample_A_1.fq.gz --reads_2 Sample_A_2.fq.gz
```

So I tried running the program in the terminal using my own files, the command was:

```
    check_strandedness --gtf Glycine_max.Glycine_max_v2.1.55.gtf \
--transcripts Glycine_max.Glycine_max_v2.1.cdna.all.fa \
--reads_1 SRR2079644.fastq
```

But it keeps giving the error

> ./how_stranded.sh: line 1: check_strandedness: command not found

I will be very thankful for any help on how to run it.

Comment: You might need to include your pip install output too.  The package [defines a set of scripts](https://github.com/signalbash/how_are_we_stranded_here/blob/f964c9bc94c99cd119a99029aeb5a73d487f14e0/setup.py#L48) that should get you `check_strandedness` in your path, and it works for me... so I bet something didn't work right during install.

Comment: Would you consider installing this in a conda environment or other virtual environment, to control the background more effectively (with regard to M__'s answer and your comment below). It sounds like there are some issues in the background that might need resolving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip` should just work, anyway... Two approaches, point 1 is a last resort approach (not recommended), I definitely recommend point 2.

First try,

```
python3 -m pip install --upgrade how_are_we_stranded_here
```

Try again does it work? Error logs?, then possibly ...

1. You need to find out where it is,

```
   pip show how_are_we_stranded_here
   pip show check_strandedness
   pip show how_stranded.sh
```

What you really want is the `check_strandedness`

```
cd ~
mkdir bin
./pathtoapp/check_stranded # make sure it works
ln -si /pathwaytoapp/how_stranded.sh /home/whatever/bin/
ln -si /pathwaytoapp/check_strandedness ~/bin/check_strandedness
```

Then write

```
export PATH="/home/whatever/bin:$PATH"
```

or modify `.profile` or `.bashrc`, then

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Try again ...

2. It is better to perform a conda installation

Install either,

- [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html) or;
- [Anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/anaconda/install/index.html)

```
    conda install -c bioconda how_are_we_stranded_here
    conda create --name stranded
    conda activate stranded
    check_strandedness -h
```

Comment: Thank you so much for taking out the time to give such a thorough reply. It definitely solved the check-strandedness issue but opened a plethora of other issues, so I just gave up.

Comment: No problem @pubsurfted, although this one is not 'solved' upvotes always welcome.

Comment: upvoted. Thank you!